# What are the parts of class names in schools?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example we have a class: `2/b` in a school. Afaik. 2 is the `grade` of the class. How should I call the `b` part?

Comment: This will be different everywhere. Different at each of my kids' schools, and from "branch" - voting to close.

Comment: Where I come from, _b_ would be the **class**, simple as that. If you’re at Hogwarts, it would be your house. If you go to school somewhere else, I’m sure it would be something different.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It can be "Second grade, branch B" but I'm not sure.